Converting non exact homogeneous differential equation to exact
Let,
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0.....(1)$$ be a non exact homogeneous differential equation. My professor told that for such differential equations, we need to multiply it by,
$$\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$$ to convert it into an exact differential equation.
However he never mentioned it's proof.
I tried a proof by multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by the mentioned factor but the thing is I am not sure how does homogeneous thing come into play. Any hint is appreciated.
My question:-
What's the proof of the fact that we need to multiply (1) by $\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$ to get an exact differential equation.
